# How to set a grep into returning only the values more than an specific one in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In a grep that i use to find some values in a log, i'm using

```
 
 -exec grep -cHF "55=36" {} \; | grep -v ":0"
```

To show me values that are different to zero, so i get this output:

```
opt/route/file_1.log:7
```

I want to know how i can set a range of numbers to show me, for example if the grep finds only 7 matches no to show me anything but if it is more than 50 ( > 50), to show me the output.

I was told that maybe something like this could work?

grep -v ':[0-7]$' but it doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: `grep -v ':[0-7]$'`

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
<INPUT> | tail -n+7
```

Comment: thanks but What worked for me was grep -ve ':[0-9]$' -e ':[12][0-9]$' -e ':3[01]$'